# WordPress removes paragraphs. How to disable this behavior?

Tags: tinymce, formatting

For example, this code:

```
<div><p>Some text here</p></div>
```

Becomes formatted as this:

```
<div>Some text here</div>
```

I think that this is MCE related behavior, because when I switch to visual editor and back to code editor all "p" tags disappear. How to disable it? Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

check this solution help full for you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var a = $('div').html();

$('div').html('<p>'+a+'</p>');

});
```

or check this url [link](https://jsfiddle.net/15wys380/)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use unobvious hacks. I solved this problem by installing "Tinymce Advanced" plugin and enable classic editor in the settings.